# check $_GET variable come from which page in php

Tags: php

I have 2 page(a.php,b.php) will send the get variable(variable name is status) to c.php.

And I get the get variable in c.php

```
<?php
$status=$_GET['status']
?>
```

And I want I can do different action for $status,That mean if $status come form a.php, i can do something and if $status come form b.php, i can do different thangs.

```
if($status is come form a.php){
    // some action   

}
elseif($status is come form b.php){
    // some action   

}
```

Now the question is how to identify to $status is come from where?
I know `$_SERVER` variable in php can help me to identify , but which variable is the best solution?

Comment: add another `$_GET` value to mark where it is coming from or pass a different `status` value for each page ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another variable `$_GET['sender'];` on both pages (A & B) to verify which one is sending the data.

And then do:

```
if($_GET['sender'] == "A"){

}
elseif($_GET['sender'] == "B"){

}
```

Comment: like a.php?status='something'&sender=A ?

Comment: Yes! But it's on `c.php?status='something'&sender=A`

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to make the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

i has this exact problem recently and its solvable in a couple of ways. infact more than a couple.

Option 1
You can use **$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']** but per the documentation it is client dependant and not call clients send it with a request so it should be considered unreliable. As noted by Darkbee in comments, it also has security flaws.

Now in my case.

option 2 - unique name on hidden field or image

```
 <form action="somepage.php">
   <input type="hidden" name="option1_name1" value="Arbitary value" />
   <input type="image" name="option1_name1" value="Arbitary value" />
 </form>
```

option 3 - same name across all forms but set a different value.

```
<form action="somepage.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="input_name1" value="unique value" />
    <input type="image" name="input_name2" value="unique value" />
</form>

<?php

     $test = $_POST;
     // just for test here. you need to process the post var
     // to ensure its safe for your code.

     // Used with option 2
     // NOTE: unique names per form on both input or submit will
     // lead to this unwieldy if else if setup.

     if (!empty($test['option1_name1'])) {
        // do this
     } else if (!empty($test['option1_name2'])) {
        // do that
     } else {
        // do the other
     }


     // Used with option 3
     // By setting all the form input names the same and setting
     // unique values instead you just check the value.
     // choose the input name you want to check the value of.

     if (!empty($test['input_name1'])) {

         switch ($test['input_name1']) {

             case 'some value':

                    // do your thing
                 break;
             case 'some other':

                    // do this thing
                 break;
             default:
                    //do the other
                 break;
         }

      }
```

Both uses have their benefits, if you have large blocks in one file, if else if would probably be prefered as you can easily find each section, but if your codes are a small block then a switch will make it easier to read.

Comment: just a sidenote : the referer can be spoofed and should never be trusted upon for security checks

Comment: Thank you for the comment darkbee, yes it should not be used to validate where a page was submitted from as a stand alone.